# rails radio button bootstrap style

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a radio button that looks like this:

[image]

Code:

```
= f.input :status, as: :radio_buttons, collection: ["Active", "Frozen", "Finished"]
```

I want it to add some styling for it to be like this:

[image]

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest solution I found:
In form:

```
= f.collection_radio_buttons :status, [[1, "Qualification"] ,[2, "Active"] ,[3, "Frozen"] ,[4, "Finished"] ,[5, "Requalified"]], :first, :last
```

In stylesheet:

```
input[type="radio"] {
  display:none;
}

label {
  ///color of borders
  border: 0.5px solid #DDD;
  border-radius:0px;
}

label:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color:red;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Gives us:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Load boostrap

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Define the radio buttons options

```
<% collection = [ { name: "Active", id: 1 }, 
                  { name: "Frozen", id: 2 }, 
                  { name: "Finished", id: 3 }
                ] %>
```

Show all options as toggle buttons

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <% collection.each do |status| %>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="<%= status[:id] %>" autocomplete="off">
        <%= status[:name] %>
      </input>
    </label>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Set classes when buttons are pressed

```
<script>
  $('.btn').on('click', function () {
    <!-- deselect all buttons and set normal color -->
    $('.btn').removeClass('active');
    $('.btn').removeClass('btn-danger');

    <!-- set current button as active and change color -->
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('btn-danger');
  });
</script>
```